# Variável em uma url pelo powershell

Tags: variáveis, url, powershell

Estou montando um script que pega uma resposta de uma url e usa esta resposta para montar uma segunda url.
Exemplo:
**$id = Invoke-WebRequest -uri "http://meusite/login?blablabla"**

Esta primeira requisição vai me retornar um valor. Ex: **123**

Minha variável fica com o valor correto. (123)

Quando vou montar uma segunda url que acontece o problema.

Estou usando:

**Invoke-WebRequest -uri "http://meusite/blebleble=" $id**

Queria que o resultado deste comando fosse "**http://meusite/blebleble=123**"
Mas está ficando assim:

http://meusite/blebleble=

123

Ai não consigo rodar a url.

O que uso entre a url e a variável?

Answer (score 1):

Concatene a string e a variável colocando ela dentro das aspas e envolvido por um `$(` `)`:

```batch
Invoke-WebRequest -uri "http://meusite/blebleble=$($id)"
```

Encontrei essa informação nessa outra [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15113467).

Comment: Funcionou certinho. Muito obrigado!

Comment: De nada, mas não esqueça de marcar a pergunta como respondida, para que outros não acessem a pergunta para responder a solução que já existe!

Comment: Esta foi a minha primeira pergunta. Desculpa a falta de conhecimento, mas não estou encontrando a opção de marcar como respondido.. é alguma opção aqui na postagem ou altero o assunto com alguma tag?

Comment: Sem problemas, seja bem-vindo! Você deve encontrar um sinal de correto cinza ao lado esquerdo das respostas, simplesmente clique nela. Ela se tornará verde e a pergunta será marcada como respondida. Para mais informações e porque aceitar uma resposta, leia essa [resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/140938)